# Searchlogic: find records between dates with time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, searchlogic

I am using Searchlogic Plugin, but I need find records between two Time's.

```
 created_at_after("02-01-2012 00:00:00") 
 created_at_before("02-01-2012 23:59:59")
```

no return nothing, but

```
 created_at_after("01-01-2012 00:00:00") 
 created_at_before("02-01-2012 23:59:59")
```

return all records createds in 01-01-2012...

Any solution?